# Running 'brew upgrade' on a schedule

Tags: upgrade, homebrew, macos

How can I run `brew upgrade` automatically on a daily schedule?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show what have you searched for and tried? Have you tried `launchd`, `cron`, `at`, or any third party tools? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854193

Answer (score 0):

You can make a daily `crontab` to run `brew upgrade`

Something like :

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
@ daily    brew upgrade
```

Find a nice tuto of how to use `brew` and `cron` [here](https://medium.com/@jsstrn/scheduling-with-cron-c5e5191663c6)